# How to rewrite a domain to a subfolder

Tags: redirect, apache2

I have one local server called server1 with a subdirectory sub (server1/sub/).
Now i have a dns entry which redirects server2 to server1.

I want to configure my apacher server in a way that when I open server2 in a browser I get the content from server1/sub/.

The url should not change to server1/sub/.

Is this possible with mod_rewrite?

EDIT:
I added

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       wiki2
127.0.0.1       wiki3
```

to the hosts file and

```
VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ServerName wiki2
  ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
  DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/wiki_angua

  <Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/wiki_angua >
     Allow From All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
  ServerName wiki3
  ServerAlias 127.0.0.1
  DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/weatherwax

  <Directory c:/xampp/htdocs/weatherwax >
     Allow From All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

to httpd.conf and restarted apache.
Whether I open wiki2 or wiki3 I land in ./wiki_angua. 
Is there anything I forgot?

Comment: How does your DNS redirection work ? Is it a proper DNS record for the server IP, or another redirection scheme ? Depending on this detail, the answers might differ significantly.

Comment: it is a proper dns record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DNS entry for `server2` then the `Host` HTTP request header will be correctly set, and all you need then is a virtual host, without the need to use mod_rewrite.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName server2

  DocumentRoot /path/to/server1/sub

  <Directory /path/to/server1/sub>
     Allow From All
  </Directory>
  # ... etc
</VirtualHost>
```

**edit**:

In the case you still want to use mod_rewrite you can do something like:

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^server2$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        /path/to/server1/sub/$1
```

This must be located in the global server configuration, and not in an existing virtual host.

Comment: for testing reason: is it possible to say server2 is localhost and 127.0.0.1 is server1

Comment: and can you show me how I can handle this with mod_rewrite (i am interested ;) )

Comment: well, yes it's possible, although more complicated, I've seen examples of this, but then name-based virtual hosting should not be used at all, I'll do an edit soon.

Comment: first thank you very much for your help. I edit my question because I have problems with testing it locally